# Is the use of spiel correct here?

Tags: vocabulary

Cambridge dictionary defines **spiel** as "A speech, especially one that is long and spoken quickly and is intended to persuade the person listening about something". Based on this, is the following sentence okay?

> She called me and gave her usual spiel about how she's broke and needs money

Comment: The sentence and use of spiel sounds okay to my native English speaking ear

Comment: Yes, this is correct, although be aware that it's somewhat informal.  If you're trying to tell an entertaining story, then this is perfect. If you're aiming for something more formal (for example, testifying in court or something like that), then you should avoid the word "spiel."

Comment: I would reserve 'spiel' for a speech made by e.g. a sales person or beggar/panhandler/Jehovah's Witness. I would not use it in connection with an 'interesting story".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"She called me and gave her usual spiel about how she's broke and needs money". This is a good use of 'spiel'.

> spiel
>
> NOUN informal
>
> An elaborate or glib speech or story, typically one
>   used by a salesperson.
>
> ‘he delivers a breathless and effortless spiel in promotion of his new
>   novel’
>
> VERB [WITH OBJECT] informal
>
> 1 Reel off; recite.
>
> ‘he solemnly spieled all he knew’
>
> 1.1no object
>
> Speak glibly or at length.
>
> ‘the barman spiels on the phone to his girlfriends’

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spiel)